# Windows service fails to read UNC-path at Windows startup

Tags: windows, winapi, service, unc

I have a windows service, which runs on windows startup. When loading, the service reads (`OpenFile`) an unc-path. The unc-path physically leads to a local path, locating on the same PC. The path looks like `"\\COMPUTER_NAME\xxx"`.
Sometimes (!) the service fails to read the path, `OpenFile` returns error code 53 (`ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`). If I restart the service later manually, everything works fine.
The UNC-path access right is full permission (Everyone, FULL).

I suspect that the error happens because the service starts earlier than some windows system services providing possibility for working with UNC.

I set up the server dependencies on `LanmanServer` and `LanmanWorkstation`, after than the error happen more rarely. Then I added dependencies on `NetBIOS` and `NetBT` - no errors yet.

The problem is that I can't find the full list of services my services has to depend on. Are the mentioned ones enough for working with UNC? Do i have to add DNS(WINS) or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a better idea to just retry if it fails with that error 53. The problem isn't really "UNC" - that's literally just a naming convention - but how the pathname is mapped to a file handle. You also need security to resolve username/passwords, which may depend on ActiveDirectory for instance. I doubt you can create a definite and stable list.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling [OpenFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile) to begin with. It's a 16-bit Windows leftover, that doesn't speak Unicode, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable "OpenFile-code" is legacy code, i don't change it because it works : -)

Comment: A generic UNC path is implemented as "\\?\UNC\server\share\<...>", which resolves in the NT namespace as "\Device\Mup\server\share\<....>". The Multiple UNC Provider (MUP) device is at the base of the device stack, and for this generic path form, it routes the "server\share\<...>" path to a UNC provider that claims ownership of the path prefix (typically just the "server\share" components). All providers are sent the path in a registered order, and the first to claim ownership is used and cached for subsequent access. We don't know which provider will claim a generic UNC path.

Comment: MUP also supports an (undocumented) explicit path form, with components that begin with a semicolon, e.g. "\Device\Mup\;LanmanRedirector\;X:<logon ID>\server\share\<...>". This tells MUP to bypass prefix resolution and use the "LanmanRedirector" device (since Vista, most filesystem redirector devices aren't named; just registered with MUP). In the latter case we also have some additional info for the redirector, telling it to use a cached connection (previously created with given credentials) that's associated with a mapped drive (X:) in a given logon session.

Comment: @ErykSun So, theoretically, one has to wait while all the NetworkProviders (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order) are initialized before work with UNC?

Comment: If you happen to know that it's an SMB share, then you're waiting for LanmanWorkstation and related dependencies such as NetBIOS and NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NetBT), and obviously the SMB server for local shares, as you discovered. However, I was just giving another reason for what MSalters advised. Just wait and try again, until it works, instead of trying to create a "definite and stable list" of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try delayed start to see if it helps. A delayed-start service is started after other auto-start services are started plus a short delay.

[image]

Refer to [SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_delayed_auto_start_info).